# How to use C# Unity Interception to log inbetween calls

Tags: c#, unity-container, unity-interception

I am currently using Unity Interceptor to implement a logging mechanism, but I cannot correctly log the information.

When I call MethodA, MethodA and MethodB is logged, but i cannot tell whether the MethodB log is due to MethodA, or some other MethodB call.

My question is how can i implement some sort of Id to link them together

expected:

[Id: 001] Method A is called

[Id: 001] Method B is called

[Id: 001] Method B completed

[Id: 001] Method A completed

current:

[Id: 001] Method A is called

[Id: 002] Method B is called

[Id: 002] Method B completed

[Id: 001] Method A completed

```
public class A() {
    [Log]
    public void MethodA() {
        var b = new B();
        b.MethodB();
    }
}

public class B() {
    [Log]
    public void MethodB () {
         // some action B
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `CallContext` to store some id and output it in the logs. The main problem will be to identify the root of a call, if you don't want to always log the id of `public static void main`...

If `MethodA` is always root, it works like this:

```
public class A() {
    [Log]
    public void MethodA() {
        CallContext.SetLogicalData( "log-id", Guid.New().ToString() )
        var b = new B();
        b.MethodB();
    }
}

public class B() {
    [Log]
    public void MethodB () {
    // some action B
    }
}

//...
public void Log( string message )
{
    _backEnd.Write( $"[Id: {CallContext.GetLogicalData( "log-id" )}] {message}" );
}
```

Comment: Hi Haukinger, using callcontext might not be ideal in my case, as I don't want any logging logic (like setting a callcontext) in function call, I want the ICallHandler to be self-contained

Comment: Then how do you want to identify functions that should trigger a new id? How should MethodA know it has to set a new id (although it's called from, say, MethodC), but MethodB should not (because it's called by MethodA)?

Comment: I can add some property to the attribute to let call handler know when to  create new id, but the problem still remain.

Comment: Does it work if you set the call context from inside the method?